# Adding firebase in Angular 13 project not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm still trying to use firebase in an Angular project. Here is the error "**Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported)**"

Before starting, here is my Angular-cli version:

```
ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 14.19.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.16
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.4
@angular/cli                    13.0.4
```

Theses are the steps, I'm following :

- Run `ng new angular-fire && cd angular-fire`
- I've created a project in Firebase (https://console.firebase.google.com) and activated authentication with Google
- Run `ng add @angular/fire` (Please, select only the option **Authentication**. We don't need the others for the moment)
- the previous command has updated your **app.module.ts**, and environment files

my app.module.ts now looks like :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp,provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth,getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth())
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, delete everything in app.component.html and add just a button :

```
<div>
  <button (click)="signIn()">Sign in with Google</button>
</div>
```

and in app.component.ts, add **signIn** function :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  getAuth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-fire';

  signIn() {
    return signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;

        console.log('errorCode', errorCode);
        console.log('errorMessage', errorMessage);
      });
  }
}
```

Finally,

- run `ng serve -o`
- open the console of your browser
- click on the button **Sign in with Google**
- you'll see this error **Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).**

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It's working now.
First, I have to install "firebase" with `npm i firebase`
Second, I've removed everything in my app.module.ts I'm now using `AngularFireModule` and `AngularFireAuthModule` from "compat". See the code and pay attention to the imports

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Next, in app.component.ts also using AngularFireAuth from "@angular/fire/compat/auth"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-fire';

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signIn() {
    return this.afAuth
      .signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
      .then((result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;

        console.log('errorCode', errorCode);
        console.log('errorMessage', errorMessage);
      });
  }
}
```

Using `ng add @angular/fire` may drop you in troubles. You must use all packages from "compat" because the new version of firebase is still under development. So if you use this command and it's not working, try using the compatibility version as explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import the AngularFireModule on app.module.ts. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. it returns this error "ERROR Error: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported)." PS: I've imported "AngularFireModule" from '@angular/fire/compat' because it's no longer exported by '@angular/fire'

Answer (score 0):

To correctly implement Firebase/GA4 in an Angular project so that tracking is done on each route. Install angular/fire using yarn or npm.

```
npm i @angular/fire
```

Then add initialization to import to `app.module.ts` and define providers.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import {
  AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
  ScreenTrackingService,
  UserTrackingService,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/analytics';

import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Remember to add Firebase settings to the project configuration (environment variables).

```
   firebase: {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX',
    authDomain: 'XXXXXX-analytics.firebaseapp.com',
    projectId: 'XXXXX-analytics',
    storageBucket: 'XXXXXX-analytics.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'CXXXXXX',
    appId: 'XXXXXX',
    measurementId: 'G-XXXXXXXX',
  },
```

The **ScreenTrackingService** and **UserTrackingService** providers ensure that default events are sent to Firebase on each route.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing a variable of type Auth (you have to import it from '@angular/fire/auth') inside the constructor of AppComponent like this.

```
import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth' //import statement


export class AppComponent  {
      constructor(private auth: Auth){}   

      //I did this, it worked for me 
}
```